# Data retrieved as "undefined" on Web SQL

Tags: javascript, phonegap, web-sql

I am trying to retrieve locally stored data using Web SQL.  However,  the data is not displayed, instead it displays "undefined".

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM RentalZ_', [], function (tx, results) {
               var len = results.rows.length;
               msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
               document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;

               for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                  msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p>";
                  document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
               }
            }, null);
         });
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show what output you get from `results.rows.item(i)`? (without the `.log`)

Comment: The output is "[object Object]"

Comment: You can loop over it and see what the object actually contains by doing something like:
`for(var property in obj) {
    alert(property + "=" + obj[property]);
}`
That way you can check whether the object actually has a property called `log`